# PHP syntax for setting a variable

Tags: php, javascript

I have a JS script which im converting the code over to PHP but am stuck on what the correct syntax is to create the same as this piece of code in JS in my PHP script:

```
var sdata = {
           "13":{
               "22":["618","22","1","1","0","0","0"],
               "21":["617","22","1","1","0","0","0"]
           },               
           "14":{
                "22":["619","22","1","1","0","0","0"],
                "20":["622","22","1","1","0","0","0"]
           },    
           "15":{
                "20":["623","22","1","1","0","0","0"]
     }
};
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If you want to convert the same object in PHP then use http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php otherwise see mata's answer.

Comment: The wrapper is an object, and the first levels are also objects and their children are arrays. Do you want the exact same structure, or you just want the data layer to be the same?

Comment: @tpaksu i wanted it like mata answered :) im not parsing the result of the variable - i'm re-writing the entire script :)

Comment: Ok then. Just to clarify the question. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sdata = array(
           "13" => array(
               "22" => array("618","22","1","1","0","0","0"),
               "21" => array("617","22","1","1","0","0","0")
           ),               
           "14" => array(
                "22" => array("619","22","1","1","0","0","0"),
                "20" => array("622","22","1","1","0","0","0")
           ),    
           "15" => array(
                "20" => array("623","22","1","1","0","0","0")
     )
);
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing to do and to be sure you're exact is to use the jQuery .get function, send this array over as part of the data, then run the PHP function json_decode on the $_GET variable to get the PHP array :) You can then print_r the array if you need to hardcode it.

Comment: true but i think they are looking for the actual coding process - not consuming JSON

Comment: Well, my idea was to consume the JSON then echo the PHP array. This way you preclude any errors creeping in by doing it manually.

Answer (score 0):

check out multidimensional arrays :

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you need is a multi-dimensional array. Since you seem to be new to PHP, check out the code examples on the array manual page from PHP:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php